# How do I find out which button submitted a form via AJAX with jQuery in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know this seems similar to other questions, but I don't think they touch on my specific problem.

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 web app, and I have an AJAX form in which I need to know which button was clicked to determine what action the user is trying to perform.

I am using submit type inputs with specific names like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Action1" value="X">
<input type="submit" name="Action2" value="X">
<input type="submit" name="Action3" value="X">
```

This is submitted by the following javascript:

```
$("form").live("submit", function (e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.mysite.com/mypage",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then in my view model I have a property that corresponds to the names of the inputs above, and a method to work out which action was requested.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Action1 {get;set;}
    public string Action2 {get;set;}
    public string Action3 {get;set;}

    public int GetAction()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Action1))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Action2))
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Action3))
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but isn't working in IE8 -> Edge. I would expect the value of the clicked input to be submitted, and the others to be null, but in IE they are all null (even the one you clicked).

**EDIT:**
I should have mentioned that if I turn javascript off it works just fine in IE, the value of the clicked input is submitted whilst the unclicked inputs come through with null values.

Comment: You can check `e.target` it will refer to element which invoke the form submit, then you can pass its name or something else

Comment: And why not `<input type="submit" name="Action" value="1" /><input type="submit" name="Action" value="2" /><input type="submit" name="Action" value="3" />`?

Comment: What outdated version of jQuery are you using that it supports live?

Comment: @epascarello I am using jQuery 1.8.3, and unfortunately can't update it for now.

Comment: @Andreas it's been a while since I worked on this, but I am pretty sure that some version of IE doesn't actually submit the value but the name of the input instead

Comment: @epascarello thanks for pointing this out, i didn't realise that live was deprecated in 1.8 too, will start using "on" instead